# Resource wrapper sealed class, error with databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, sealed-class

I'm stuck on a little issue using [`Resource`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#addendum) wrapping around my data, I don't know how I can use it in my databinding.

**Sealed class**:

```kotlin
sealed class Resource<out T: Any> {
    data class Success<out T: Any>(val data: T): Resource<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Throwable): Resource<Nothing>()
    object Loading: Resource<Nothing>()
}
```

I've got this `val product: LiveData<Resource<NetworkProductDetails>>`

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="my.package.ProductDetailsViewModel" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{viewModel.product.productName}"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    ...
</layout>
```

I've got an issue because `viewModel.product` is not a `NetworkProductDetails` but `Resource<NetworkProductDetails>` and my XML/Databinding doesn't know how to process it.

---

I've found a way to make work but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

**First Solution:**

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="my.package.ProductDetailsViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="product"
            type="my.package.NetworkProductDetails" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{product.productName}"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    ...
</layout>
```

```kotlin
viewModel.product.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { it ->
    when(it) {
        is Resource.Success -> {
            binding.product = it.data
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Solution:**

In the comment I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking around, there is 2 solutions I've found, the first is in my original post and the second is the one below:

Creating a function in my sealed class to expose the data if it is `Success` and then be able to use it in my `xml`

Pros:

- No need to create a special `BindingAdapter` that could hide some of the logic
- No need to add more code in every `Fragment` like in Solution 1

Cons:

- I feel that it breaks the point of having a wrapper

```kotlin
sealed class Resource<out T: Any> {
    data class Success<out T: Any>(val data: T): Resource<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Throwable): Resource<Nothing>()
    object Loading: Resource<Nothing>()

    fun toData(): T? = if(this is Success) this.data else null
}
```

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text='@{viewModel.product.toData().productName}'
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Won't this cause a crash when it tries to get "productName" on null data?

Answer (score 5):

> I've got an issue because viewModel.product is not a NetworkProductDetails but Resource and my XML/Databinding doesn't know how to process it.

You missed the `data`. Even if you wound up with a `Resource.Success`, `productName` is not a property of `Resource` or even `Resource.Success`. `data` is a property of `Resource.Success`, and I assume that `productName` is a property of `NetworkProductDetails`. Your expression has no `data`.

You also would need to teach data binding about your other two cases (`Loading`, `Error`) and what to do in them.

In the best case scenario, you might be able to pull off a binding expression like this:

```
android:text='@{viewModel.product instanceof Resource.Success ? viewModel.product.data.productName : "like, whatever"}'
```

However:

- I don't know if `instanceof` will handle the generic well
- I don't know if you can refer to the `LiveData` output twice in a single expression

Alternatively, you could try creating a binding adapter for `Resource<NetworkProductDetails>` that handles the three cases, though I have never tried that for a type that uses generics.

Comment: I've found another way, I've updated it in my post, could you give me your insight ?

Comment: @Biscuit: If you do not mind having that `toData()` function, then that would work. You might want to pull that out of the question and post it as your own answer.