# Using Resource wrapper with multiple entities and mapper classes in clean architecture android

Tags: android, kotlin, wrapper, clean-architecture, mapper

Let's say we have an app that is going to apply clean architecture principles.
we have repositories, data sources(local & remote), multiple value objects for each layer and mapper classes for mapping those objects.

There is also a wrapper class called Resource (similar to what is discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805466/resource-wrapper-sealed-class-error-with-databinding)).

for example:

```
interface PriceRepository {
    suspend fun getPrices(): Resource<PriceData>
}

interface PriceRemoteDataSource {
    suspend fun getPrices(): Resource<RemotePriceData>
}

interface PriceLocalDataSource {
    suspend fun getPrices(): Resource<PriceDataEntity>
}

interface Mapper<I, O> {
    fun mapTo(input: I): O
}

class PriceRepositoryImpl: PriceRepository {
    override suspend fun getPrices() {
        val localPrices: Resource<PriceDataEntity> = localDataSource.getPrices()
        val remotePrices: Resource<RemotePriceData> = remoteDataSource.getPrices()
     
        // Some logic ...
        
        // Map results to Resource<PriceData> and return them? how?
    }
}
```

Now my questions are:

1. How and where the mapping between different entities should happen? if it happens inside the repository, how should it be implemented (since we are wrapping objects inside Resource)?
2. I am exposing Resource from data sources in order to catch any exceptions inside them and only send the final result in a common format, is this a good practice? if not, where is the better place to handle errors?

Comment: `localDataSource.getPrices()` is returning data wrapped in `Resource`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.